# How to "lift" a path to the tangent bundle?

Tags: differential-geometry, category-theory, manifolds

Given a path $c: (-\epsilon,\epsilon)=I \to M$ in a manifold.

Define $\widetilde c:I \to TM$ (a kind of "lift") as the curve $t_0 \mapsto [c(t+t_0)] \in T_{c(t_0)}M$.

Is there a nice categorical definition of this "lift" using commutative diagrams in the smooth category?

My aim is to be able to say: $c: I \to M$ is an integral curve of $X$ iff $\widetilde c = Xoc$

Comment: I would recommend splitting this up into three separate questions.

Comment: I don't understand how you're defining $\tilde c$. Is $[c(t)]$ you notation for the equivalence class of a differentiable curve at $t=0$ representing $c'(0)$? Thinking of a point in $TM$ as a point in $M$ together with a tangent vector at that point, I think it would be easier to think about if you wrote $\tilde c(t) = \big(c(t),c'(t)\big)$. Your vector field $X$ is now being interpreted as a section of $TM$, so writing $\tilde c(t) = X(c(t))$ makes perfectly good sense, and, yes, you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such "categorically defined lift," at least in the sense that it natural. This is an essential point in the definition of connection, the fact that there is no canonically defined lift for vetors to their tangent bundle. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehresmann_connection

If you are in a Riemannian manifold, the situation is slightly less hopeless. There is a unique torsion free metric connection (the Levi-Civita connection.) You can then consider the lits defined by such connection.