What is the name for this kind of curve in the tangent bundle?
Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, let $TM$ be its tangent bundle and let $c : [0,1] \to TM$ be a smooth path. For each $t \in [0,1]$, the point $c(t)$ is of the form $(x(t), v(t))$ where $x(t) \in M$ and $v(t) \in T_{x(t)}(M)$. We can differentiate the map $x : [0,1] \to M$, obtaining a vector $x'(t) \in T_{x(t)}(M)$. Thus, it makes sense to ask whether or not $x'(t) = v(t)$.
What is the name for a path $c$ where the answer is yes for all $t$?
Given a path $x : [0,1] \to M$, there is a unique path $c : [0,1] \to TM$ lifting $x$. What is the name for this unique lifting construction?

Oddly, in googling for the answer to this question, I found https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1204617/ and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4035998 , both of which seem to me to be asking a very similar question, and both of which have answers saying that you need to choose a connection on the tangent bundle to answer this. I am pretty sure that what I am saying does not require a connection, so I tried to spell it out as clearly as possible.

I guess you could call it a "derivative", or a "tangent curve". Normally if $u:I \to M$,  then $u': I \to TM$, subject to $u'(t)$ lying in $T_{u(t)} M$. If $M$ happens to be embedded in $R^k$ for some large $k$, then you can think of $TM$ as pairs $(p, v)$, where $p \in M \subset \mathbb R^k$, and $v \in \mathbb R^k$, but restricted to just those vectors $v$ tangent to $M$ at $p$. In this case, what I've called $u'$ can be written $u'(t) = (u(t), v(t))$, where $v(t) = \frac{d}{dt} u(t)$, so it really has exactly the form you're describing.

Apologies for using $u'$ to indicate the tangent curve, but $\frac{d}{dt}$ to indicate the "second year calc" derivative of a function from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R^k$. Whitney's paper on the Whitney-Graustein theorem spends some time on the idea of separating $u$ from $v$ -- adjiusting $v$ a bit, and then re-integrating it to get a slightly distorted version of $u$ (which is then further adjusted to make $u$ remain a closed path), thus defining a regular homotopy of loops. But I don't think he ever gives a name to these "tangent" (or non-tangent) curves.

I agree with @John thst this is the image of the derivative mapping induced from $TI$ to $TM$. (Just evaluate canonically at the tangent vector $1$ to $I$.) It does not fit the discussion of the linked questions because you are not lifting the curve by specifying anything about the *tangent$ vectors of the lift. That’s where a connection may come into play.

Thanks, Ted, for clearing up my not-terribly-clear wording.

In the case you work with a tangent bundle, this sometimes goes by the name of natural lift or tangent lift (of $x(t)$) .
However, the most common terminology , at least in the jet-bundle literature, is prolongation. What you do is you consider $x$ as a section of the bundle $M\times\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$, and you ``prolong it'' to a section of the bundle $J^1\pi:=TM\times\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ taking its derivative. This construction works as well when you have a more general bundle $P\to \mathbb{R}$ (in your case, $P=M\times\mathbb{R}$).
